# Can't get Ansible playbook to run when specifying a tag

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get a playbook to run a play when specifying a tag, however, when I run the playbook with the tags, it still doesn't run it. What am I missing?

```
- hosts: slaves
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: 'update packages'
    raw: 'sudo apt-get update'
  - name: 'install python'
    raw: 'sudo apt-get -y install python --fix-missing'
  - import_role:
      name: dj-wasabi.telegraf
  tags:
    - telegraf
```

Running `ansible-playbook site.yml --tags "telegraf"` will skip this play.

The output is:

```
PLAY [slaves] ***************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

When running with `--list-tasks`:

```
play #2 (slaves): slaves  TAGS: [telegraf]
  tasks:
    update packages   TAGS: [telegraf]
    install python    TAGS: [telegraf]
    include_tasks TAGS: [telegraf]
```

Comment: What's the output ? Does it work when you doesn't specify the tag ? Is this all the playbook `site.yml` ? Can you rerun the command with `--list-tasks` and show the output ?

Comment: The only other play (first one) populates the inventory dynamically.

Comment: No I can't read this you need to edit your question to include more details.

Comment: Also `no hosts matched` clearly shows that you have no hosts to run this play against. This is not a tag problem. Tag works fine.

Comment: You are right. It went absolutely over my head. The issue was I was not tagging the play that dynamically populates the inventory. Thank you very much!

Comment: For the next time, try to edit your question to include more information and don't post them in comment so it is easier to read for future readers.

Comment: Thank you. As you can see I don't come around here too much. I will take into consideration for future questions, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hosts to run the play against, that's why you get the message:

```
skipping: no hosts matched
```

---

Add the flag `--list-tasks` to see the tasks that match the tag:

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --tags "telegraf" --list-tasks
```

Since it displayed the tasks it means the tag works fine.